# Python program doesn't return links from http://xkcd.com/353 (Udacity Intro to CS course)

Tags: python-3.x, search, computer-science

```
def get_page(url):
    try:
        import urllib
        return urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    except:
        return "error"


def get_next_target(page):
    start_link = page.find('<a href=')

    if start_link == -1:
        return None, 0
    else:
        start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
        end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
        url = page[start_quote + 1:end_quote]
        return url, end_quote


def print_all_links(page):
    while True:
        url, endpos = get_next_target(page)
        if url:
            print(url)
            page = page[endpos:]
        else:
            break

print_all_links(get_page('http://xkcd.com/353'))
```

I passed all my quizzes but the def get_page was not shown on video but the code was given in a long sentence below the video.
However it does print links if they are entered as a string on the last line print_all_links('string').

Answer (score 1):

I found out the above code I posted earlier works in Python 2, but not Python 3. I changed the import and return in def get_page(url) to reflect Py3 requirements and also added the .decode('utf-8') which fixed the TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

```
def get_page(url):
try:
    import urllib.request
    return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
except:
    return "error"
```